# How to extends ListActivity where AppCompatActivity in Android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-listview

I want to use Activity extends ListActivity for PullToRefresh.But i have use CustomActionBar that's why using AppCompatActivity.How to solve this issue.Thanks in Advanced

```
public class CustomActionActivity extends ListActivity

public class PullToRefreshActivity extends ListActivity {
    private LinkedList<String> mListItems;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pull_to_refresh);

        // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
        ((PullToRefreshListView) getListView()).setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefreshListView.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // Do work to refresh the list here.
                new GetDataTask().execute();
            }
        });

        mListItems = new LinkedList<String>();
        mListItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(mStrings));

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListItems);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Instead of this:

```
public class CustomActionActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I have trouble understanding the question. Can you try to clarify?

Comment: In my activity PullToRefresh is not working properly so that i want to use ListActivity. See i have edited my post with PullToRefreshActivity .

Comment: Consider using RecyclerView. This is newest api http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use ListView in your app then directly use it without extending ListActivity. Like this

```
public class PullToRefreshActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private LinkedList<String> mListItems;
PullToRefreshListView listView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pull_to_refresh);
    listView = (PullToRefreshListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view); 
    // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
    listView.setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefreshListView.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // Do work to refresh the list here.
            new GetDataTask().execute();
        }
    });

    mListItems = new LinkedList<String>();
    mListItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(mStrings));

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListItems);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the **Java doucmentation** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/multipleinheritance.html we can't inherit multiple classes. So, if you want both the functionaloty then use `ListView` inside your layout.