# Unable to extend AppCompatActivity as i'm already extending ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar, twitterkit

I'm using TwitterKit to load a list of tweets in an activity. I would like to add a custom ActionBar to my activity. I'm unable to find a way to extend both AppCompatActivity and ListActivity at the same time...  Are there any workarounds or solutions for this?  Please see code below

```
public class travel_info extends ListActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_travel_info);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_line_info);
        View view = getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();


        Twitter.initialize(this);
        final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
                .screenName("TfLTravelAlerts")
                .build();
        final TweetTimelineListAdapter adapter = new TweetTimelineListAdapter.Builder(this)
                .setTimeline(userTimeline)
                .build();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: the solution is to not extend ListActivity and not use a listview. Then you can extend AppCompatActivity and use a recyclerview

Comment: also please `class travel_info` use standard java naming conventions

Comment: There is no way to extend both classes which is not possible in java(Multiple inheritence).. Why you want to extend it?

Comment: i dont think this a duplicate it is a totally diff question@TimCastelijns

Comment: Possibly a duplicate!?  However, @TimCastelijns, I change to a RecyclerView and all works great now! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes. Duplicate. The question is not 100% the same, but similar enough. Even the answers/solution are the same. @AmitVaghela you can think what you want, but you also think that saying "you can only extend a single class" is a good answer to this question

Comment: check answer first@TimCastelijns

Answer (score -1):

**You can only Extend a single class**. And implement Interfaces from many sources.

Extending multiple classes is not available.

you could use `ListActivity` or `ListView` inside regular `Activity`. In the newest versions of Android, preferred way of displaying items on a list is using so called [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

Please, see linked documentation. It's quite good and helpful. Besides naming convetion, `RecyclerView` gives you more flexibility and has *ViewHolder* pattern implemented out-of-the-box for re-using views during the scrolling what increases application's performance. Before introducing `RecyclerView`, you had to implement *ViewHolder* pattern on your own.

Instead of `Activity` or `ListActivity`, you should use `AppCompatActivity` and place `RecyclerView` inside it to keep backward compatibility with older systems and devices.

Comment: how do you suppose an inner class would solve this issue? and what would the inner class be?

Comment: inner class not will here but can use only on class to extend

Comment: *The only solution I can think of is not inheriting either class* - that's not what I would call a solution

Comment: @TimCastelijns already updated answer

Comment: @Aaron Strickland isn't your issue solved?

Comment: *@TimCastelijns, I change to a RecyclerView and all works great now! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.*

Answer (score -1):

> I'm unable to find a way to extend both AppCompatActivity and ListActivity at the same time

If you want to use ListView in your app then directly use it without extending ListActivity See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34328384/2462531)

Comment: listactivity is a builtin class